# How to install Windows 10 on a non-bootable PCIe NVMe?

Tags: windows, uefi, nvme

I have an old PC which can recognize M.2 NVMe ssd on PCIe adapter, but the UEFI BIOS does not support booting from the NVME. And there is no BIOS update for my motherboard (Giga-B75m-D3V).

For Linux, as a workaround, I can put `/boot` and `/boot/EFI` mount points on a SATA drive, and put `/` on the NVMe, such that I can still get the performance gain from the SSD under Linux.

For Windows 10, I can start/finish the Windows 10 install process and select NVMe SSD as the destination drive (this implies that Windows 10 can recognize SSD), but after reboot, the BIOS can not boot from the NVMe.

I am wondering, is there a similar workaround to install Windows 10 on the NVMe SSD?

Answer (score 1):

After modifying the UEFI BIOS of the mother board, the PC can boot from the PCIe SSD now. I follow the [instructions from here](https://winraid.level1techs.com/t/howto-get-full-nvme-support-for-all-systems-with-an-ami-uefi-bios/30901#msg14810) for modifying the BIOS. Specifically, I use `UEFITool` to insert the `NvmExpressDxe_small.ffs` in the original BIOS, then flash the new bios into the motherboard. The original BIOS contains menu for save/flash BIOS.

Note that after updating BIOS, the boot mode has changed to CSM mode, under which Windows 10 refuses to install on the NVMe SSD. I need to change boot mode to UEFI-only for installing Windows.

Btw, for me, the process is a kind of too smooth to be true, since I did not expect it will work on the first try. Why the inserted DXE driver just works? I guess there are several dependencies for this to work:

- The UEFI BIOS already contain PCIe related DXE drivers which enumerate all PCIe devices.
- The new DXE driver do not explicitly require any dependency to load, which is true (it contains no DXE dependency section).

Comment: In case the SecureFlash crap (which may not exists in older UEFI) blocks you from flashing a modifed firmware, or if you are afraid of bricking it, you can even sideload the DXE with a script for EDK2 Shell. While in that case you'll still need e.g. a USB drive for the early booting, at least you can then have the ESP on the NVMe drive as well. I am using the DXE from OVMF with an AMI UEFI in that way.

Comment: I think it still requires a bit of "luck" anyway. AFAIK the NVMe DXE does not consists of code that deals with all the PCIe stuff. Rather it just deals with the block device (i.e. storage drive / NVMe protocol) stuff. So it still needs to be somewhat compatible with the other parts of the firmware.

Comment: Yes, a "bit" of luck, you are absolutely right on that.